# How to send hyperlink with SendGrid using Python

Tags: python, email, hyperlink, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a simple mail with SendGrid which must contain one hyperlink.

I'm not doing anything fancy, just following the [documentation example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#with-mail-helper-class) with some changes

```
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("test@example.com")
to_email = To("test@example.com")
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"

content = Content("text/html", '<html><a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></html>')

mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

It looks fine to me, but once I run the script and the mail is sent, it shows up like plain text I cannot click on.

I also tried many other combinations removing the `<html>` tag, using single and double quotes with the backslash, but nothing really worked. I even tried to do the same thing without the [Mail Helper Class](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#without-mail-helper-class), but it didn't work.

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
content = Content(

    "text/html", "Hi User, \n This is a test email.\n This is to also check if hyperlinks work <a href='https://www.google./com'> Google </a> Regards Karthik")
```

This helped me. I believe you don't need to mention the html tags